# Executar aplicativo externo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Qual o código devo utilizar para iniciar um aplicativo externo de um computador a partir de uma página HTML?

Numa outra vez me disseram que seria este código em JavaScript:

```
var shwll = new ShellObject();
var hproc="C:\Windows\notepad.exe";
shwll.exec(hproc);
```

Mas não obtive nenhum resultado.

Comment: Em que ambiente esse código está executando? O `ShellObject` é específico da Microsoft, e pelo que entendi destinado a ser embutido em programas do Visual Basic. Não há suporte a `ShellObject` no browser. Razões de segurança... Mesmo o HTML5 - que oferece diversas opções de integração com o seu ambiente - não foi tão longe a ponto de permitir acesso ao shell (que eu saiba). *Talvez* você consiga algo desse tipo com um Applet Java (*trusted*), mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 9):

HTML não é uma linguagem de programação. Não é com HTML que isso é possível, mas sim com linguagens de script como Javascript e VBScript.

Com nenhuma linguagem você conseguirá fazer isso **a partir de um navegador**. O motivo é segurança. Se  fosse possível executar programas arbitrariamente na máquina cliente, não seria nada difícil para um hacker forçar o download de um código malicioso para ser compilado e executado em sua máquina. No mínimo daria pra conseguir todas as senhas armazenadas no seu computador, e em pior caso você daria acesso às suas contas bancárias a um desconhecido.

O Windows tem um executável chamado Wscript.exe. Vou deixar a cargo de quem for curioso encontrá-lo. Esse executável é capaz de executar Javascript localmente, com permissões de administrador. O ambiente é diferente do navegador - você não terá acesso a várias coisas, como *Web Storage*. Em compensação objetos como o `ShellObject` se tornam acessíveis, e você pode inclusive manipular arquivos.

Não sou especialista em `Node.js`, mas como é um ambiente servidor e não cliente, você é capaz de acessar mais recursos do sistema operacional com ele do que via navegador, de certa forma. Mas não tenho certeza se ele é capaz de acessar o `ShellObject`.

Além do node e do Wscript, existem vários outros ambientes para Javascript que permitem <strike>fuçar máquinas alheias e destruir arquivos</strike> acessar componentes do sistema operacional de forma menos restrita do que via navegador. É só questão de pesquisar.

Agora, se a intenção era realmente acessar o *shell* pelo navegador... Ao invés de Javascript use componentes *COM* ou *ActiveX*. E entenda que isso provavelmente só vai funcionar no Internet Explorer, versão 6 ou inferior. Boa sorte.

Comment: Mas retratando um tópico:

Tipo o site da Google quando você vai até a página de instalação do Google Chrome e você clica em "Baixar" o site não faz o download de nenhum arquivo mas sim executa um programa compatível com o Framework. E Então?

Comment: Eles deixam você baixar um executável, e você tem a opção de salvar ou executar. Dá uma olhada no script deles também pra ver as "mágicas" que eles fazem ;)

Answer (score 6):

Não é possível, o melhor que você pode fazer é pedir explicitamente para o usuário por vontade própria envie o arquivo para o seu servidor e você fazer alguma coisa com ele no servidor. É uma questão de segurança. As pessoas confiam que aplicações *web* não o colocarão em risco, então o software que controla isto, no caso o navegador, precisa garantir isto pra ele. E ele confiará nos navegadores que fazem isto bem.

Claro que é possível através de navegadores personalizados ou *plugins* que permitem acesso irrestrito. Mas não conte que alguém vá instalar algo assim em seu computador. Na verdade hoje ninguém quer instalar nada, mesmo que seja confiável e só traga vantagens.

Além disto é possível usar a nova [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html). Não está disponível universalmente ([está em todos os navegadores relevantes modernos](http://caniuse.com/fileapi)) e tem várias limitações. Você não pode pegar o arquivo do usuário que você quiser. Apenas o que você mesmo produziu e tem acesso, além do que você tem autorização explícita do usuário.

Execução não está entre as atividades possíveis destes arquivos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

### **Executa em JavaScript**

```
<script>
 function Execultar(){
 var shell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.shell" );
 shell.run( '"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"', 1, true );}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="Execultar();">Iniciar</a>
```

Executa o bloco de notas funciona no Internet Explorer demais não testados.

**Ou dessa forma via VBS em html**

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Exec("cmd /c start notepad.exe")
</script>
```

Testado no Internet Explorer

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: `ActiveXObject` só funciona no InternetExplorer, ou seja não ira funcionar em navegadores como Chrome, Firefox, Windows 8 Apps e MS Edge. Além disto mesmo que limitemos o usuário ao uso do IE ainda sim no máximo isto irá executar um aplicativo que exista na máquina, se não existir irá ocorrer um erro qualquer. No máximo esse código pode ser interessante como atalho para algum dashboard, todavia não vejo utilidade alguma depois disso. Deveria alertar o autor da pergunta e não só dar um código.