# Criar um atalho através do Navegador

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome

É possível criar um atalho através do navegador? Seja lá como, se for com JavaScript, Java, ou qualquer coisa que faça isso possível.

Eu preciso criar um atalho no desktop do usuário através do navegador, da mesma forma que o Chrome faz quando abre aquele menu "Criar atalho de aplicativos".

Já cheguei a ver algumas pessoas falando que dá para fazer através do ActiveX do Internet Explorer, mas eu queria fazer isso através do Chrome ou qualquer navegador.

Comment: Isto não é possível com JavaScript. É uma característica de segurança.

Comment: Será que rola com java então?? Ou qualquer solução que não seja necessário instalar coisas no PC do usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível.

O navegador é um [*sandbox*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29). Isto é necessário porque ele permite executar códigos arbitrários criados por desconhecidos no computador do usuário. Precisa ter muita restrição para isto não sair do controle.

Então qualquer operação que exija interação fora do navegador precisa de autorização explícita do usuário. O pedido de autorização precisa ser muito simples, algo que ele entenda o que está acontecendo. Porque senão vira algo comum em eleições onde as pessoas votam sem saber porque, aí causam mal para si mesmas e nem perceber o que estão fazendo. Então o navegador deixa o usuário fazer bem poucas coisas a pedido de uma página.

É possível através de *plugins* mas provavelmente não é uma solução para você, a pessoa teria que instalá-lo e ninguém mais quer fazer isto, especialmente um *plugin* desconhecido. Mesmo *plugins* existentes como o Java também impõe restrições.

Todo mundo precisa entender que o ambiente do desenvolvedor *web* é o navegador, não pode fazer nada fora dele. Se alguém quer fazer algo fora precisa fazer uma aplicação *desktop*. É, ainda existe este tipo de aplicação e ela tem uma série de vantagens.

É o mesmo princípio que já respondi [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47697/101).