# Abrir link PHP em outro navegador

Tags: php, link

Gostaria de abrir um link que possuo em minha página em um navegador específico (IE). Por exemplo, se estou usando Google Chrome, gostaria de abrir o link no Internet Explorer quando clicado. 
Há alguma função em PHP para me auxiliar?

Comment: abrir o browser no lado do cliente ou do servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Existe duas funções no php que podem lhe auxiliar o [exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) e [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)

Exemplo usando o `exec`:

```
exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe http://www.google.com.br");
```

> Porém isto funcionará em localhost, mas, não funcionará na web, pois o PHP roda no servidor, e sendo assim ele não tem acesso aos diretórios do cliente.

**OBS:** Isso irá abrir o navegador no servidor, e não no lado do cliente.

**OBS 2:** Se fosse possível, não tem como saber se o cliente tem determinado navegador instalado.

**OBS 3:** Na minha opinião isso viola o direito de escolha do cliente, pois se o cliente escolhe usar o navegador `X`, ele tem seus motivos e com certeza ele não gostaria de clicar em um link e abrir o navegador `Y`.

Referências:

[Hardware](http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/abrir-navegador/1240066/)

[iMasters](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/400758-resolvidoabrir-pagina-em-um-navegador-expecifico/)

Comment: Isto abre um browser no servidor. Não sei se é isto que o Rodrigo pretende. Se o servidor for remoto, isto não tem grande utilidade.

Comment: @BlunT, ele não específico na pergunta, porém já acrescentei na resposta que só roda no servidor.

Comment: Seria necessário abrir em navegador específico, pois o conteúdo carregado neste link abre apenas no IE. É uma intranet e roda local. Não há a possibilidade de fazer isto com estas funções?

Comment: Uma solução caso usem `Firefox` seria usar o `Firefox Open With`, e os usuários/clientes estarem cientes que determinado link só abre no `IE`. http://pplware.sapo.pt/browsers/firefox-open-with-abrir-links-com-outros-browsers/

Comment: Mas queríamos mesmo que o link chamasse o IE com o endereço passado. Local, na máquina do cliente.

Comment: Alguém teria um exemplo no PHP deste uso: exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe http://www.google.com.br"); ?

Comment: Como eu disse, isto não é possível, pois o PHP não roda no lado do cliente e sim no servidor, essas funções chamaram o navegador no lado do servidor e não do cliente.

Comment: Consegui o que preciso da seguinte forma: $output = shell_exec('start iexplore.exe http://www.seusite.com.br');

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto, no lado do cliente? o cliente ao clicar no link abrira o `IE`?

Comment: No lado do cliente quando ele clica no link, chama uma função que faça isto: $output = shell_exec('start iexplore.exe seusite.com.br'); E sim irá abrir o IE! :)

Comment: Já testo no cliente? ou testo localmente?

Comment: Testei no servidor agora e realmente não funciona ;(. Não abre na tela do cliente e sim na tela do servidor.  Não é possível então?

Comment: Pessoal, desculpa a inversão das palavras. Anteriormente funcionou no servidor e no lado do cliente não funciona.

Comment: É o que está escrito na resposta, que não é possível fazer isto, o que pode ser feito é adaptar o link(página) para funcionar nos outros navegadores, ou os clientes/usuários estarem cientes que só funciona no `IE`.

Comment: Ok. E nem usando alguma coisa em javascript não funcionaria?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29286/executar-aplicativo-externo-com-javascript

Comment: É, então não tem jeito. Desculpa o incomodo ;(